# Is it true that F2n is divided by Fn (Fibonacci)

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

How can I prove that $F_{2n}$ is divisible by $F_n$ in the Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: Do you mean " is divisible by"?

Comment: This question, or variants,  seems to be coming up a lot over the past few days.  Anyway, [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/FibonacciGCD.shtml) is a reference.

Comment: In fact, $F_{2n} = F_n (F_{n+1} + F_{n-1})$.  (My favorite proof of this: if $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, then $A^n = \begin{bmatrix} F_{n+1} & F_n \\ F_n & F_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}$.  Now write $A^{2n} = (A^n)^2$ and compare the two sides.)

Comment: Since $(x^n-y^n)\mid (x^{2n}-y^{2n})$, it is a straightforward consequence of the closed formula for Fibonacci numbers. Actually $F_{2n}=L_n F_n$ where $L_n$ is the $n$-th Lucas number.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think it's a bit more complex than that, since $x$ and $y$ are irrational.  You would still be left with showing $x^n + y^n$ is an integer.

Comment: @DanielSchepler which is easy to show

Comment: @DanielSchepler: $x,y$ are conjugated roots for a monic quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients, so $x^n+y^n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Or, simply, that is true for $n=0,n=1$ and $H_{n}=x^n+y^n$ fulfills $H_{n+2}=H_{n+1}+H_n$.

Comment: Granted, it's not hard to show if you know about solutions to recurrences, or about symmetric polynomials; but otherwise, on its own as a problem out of the blue, it wouldn't be obvious.